# Trying to identify a component; I followed traces and made a schematic with surrounding components

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Scheme]

The component is labeled IC2 in this schematic. A lot of the traces were connected to GND, some were not connected. Could anyone identify the component by this context?

Comment: Welcome! More information is needed. What's on the other side of the BSP126? Is that test point ground? Also, pro EE tip: please draw your circuits with positive voltages pointing up, negative (or ground) down and with input to the left and output to the right. Any markings on the mystery chip? A photo of it?

Comment: Does the IC have any markings? Can you provide a photograph of the board?

Comment: Ty you guys for the tip! The component is burnt and has expoloded so no markings on it. I will provide an image of the circuitboard tomorrow :)

Comment: Pinout and supply voltage make me think it's 4000-series CMOS logic of some sort ...

Comment: It'll almost certainly be one of the "quad 2-input" logic devices like a 4001, 4011, 4070, 4071 or similar, and only one of the logic gates is being used (pins 1, 2 & 3). But from what you've shown use here there's no way to figure out which one of those (which logic function - NOR, NAND, XOR, OR, ...) it could be. You'll need to figure out what signals arrive at pins 1 & 2 and how you'd expect them to control that "MICREL200" device.

Comment: I have now updated with more pictures, and also the broken component, there is still some readable text on it.

Comment: The readable text looks like a date or batch code, so probably not much use. You need to try to get more info on what the signals arriving at pins 1 & 2 are and/or where they come from, and what that MICREL200 part does to be able to figure out what logic function might be fulfilled by your toasted IC2.